# Defining a variable in python from dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm struggling with my understanding of lists vs. dictionaries and the best uses of each as well as how to handle the data as I'm trying to learn.

For instance, I have the following data in a CSV file:

```
device,parent,fexprefix
2248_1,5548_1,Eth101/1/
2248_2,5548_2,Eth102/1/
2248_3,5548_3,Eth103/1/
```

I created a dictionary out of it by doing the following:

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('fexmap2.csv'))
fexdata = {}
for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.iteritems():
        fexdata.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
```

Now I can print out my dictionary as follows:

```
{'device': ['2248_1', '2248_2', '2248_3'], 'fexprefix': ['Eth101/1/', 'Eth102/1/', 'Eth103/1/'], 'parent': ['5548_1', '5548_2', '5548_3']}
```

I can see my keys:

```
>>>fexdata.keys()
['device', 'fexprefix', 'parent']
```

So far so good I suppose.

But now I need to do lookups against this data to derive new variables (hope that's the right term).

For instance, I will be parsing some JSON data where I will learn about the device ***"2248_1"***.

From that, I need to look up what it's parent is in the dictionary to create a variable I can start to use in the script.

Let's say when I get that ***"2248_1"*** from JSON it is defined as:

```
destdevice = 2248_1
```

So now I want to say something like this in layman's terms:

```
if destdevice is found in fexdata['device']
then deviceparent = fexdata['parent'] of fexdata['device']
```

At which point, `deviceparent = 5548_1`

Comment: Consider using an alternate structure for your dict. Make the `device` id the key, and the value a tuple of `(parent,fexprefix)`. That way you'll be able to get the `parent` and `fexprefix` quickly for any `device`.

Comment: I think you are on to something and most likely that is exactly what I need to do.  Would you happen to have an example of how that would be accomplished?

Comment: Ok using what you stated as well as the other info from others this works better for my needs I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device is to be used as a key, make it the key of your dictionary:

```
fexdata = {}
for row in reader:
    fexdata[row['device']] = row
```

You can then directly get the parentid of device with id 2248_1:

```
destdevice = '2248_1'
deviceparent = fexdata[destdevice]['parent']
```

Answer (score 1):

With your defined data structure you have to check if the item is in the list within your dictionary, get the index of the item and return another item from the parent list. Like this:

```
if destdevice in fexdata['device']:
    parentindex = fexdata['device'].index(destdevice)
    deviceparent = fexdata['parent'][parentindex]
```

This of course breaks down if you ever have to add a device without it having a parent, as your data structure relies on the index of device being the same as the index of the parent and that there never is duplicate devices (with non-unique names) with differing parents.

example using your dataset:

```
>>> fexdata = {'device': ['2248_1', '2248_2', '2248_3'], 'fexprefix': ['Eth101/1/', 'Eth102/1/', 'Eth103/1/'], 'parent': ['5548_1', '5548_2', '5548_3']}
>>> destdevice = '2248_1'
>>> if destdevice in fexdata['device']:
...     parentindex = fexdata['device'].index(destdevice)
...     deviceparent = fexdata['parent'][parentindex]
...
>>> deviceparent
'5548_1'
```

Comment: I appreciate the insight.  I understand the concern with the integrity of data not having duplicates or empty fields.  This is a case where that will not be an issue, except by accident of course.  One question though... fexdata['device'] will never have the same name as another.  However fexdata['parent'] can be the same name for different fexdata['device'] correct?  That shouldn't break things from the perspective of this?

Comment: as long as the fexdata['parent][i] has the same index (it was added at the same time as the fexdata['device'][i], it will yield correct answer. The drawback here is that fexdata['parent'] will be larger than neccessery, but it will still work. I.e. duplicatded in fexdata['parent'] do not matter or break the integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Using all the info from the replies it was pointed out that my first mistake is in how I was handling the data.  I really needed to make just one key based on 'device'.

As that is what all other lookups really depend on.

So I did the following:

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('fexmap2.csv'))
fexdata = {}
for row in reader:
    fexdata[row['device']] = row
```

This in turn gives me this dict:

```
{'2248_3': {'device': '2248_3', 'fexprefix': 'Eth103/1/', 'parent': '5548_3'}, '2248_2': {'device': '2248_2', 'fexprefix': 'Eth102/1/', 'parent': '5548_2'}, '2248_1': {'device': '2248_1', 'fexprefix': 'Eth101/1/', 'parent': '5548_1'}}
```

I can then find the info I need based on the device as such:

```
destdevice = '2248_1'
deviceparent = fexdata[destdevice]['parent']
fexprefix = fexdata[destdevice]['fexprefix']

print deviceparent
5548_1
print fexprefix
Eth101/1/
```

At this point this definitely appears to be more in line with what I needed and hoped to accomplish.  Now I will see if I run into any gotchas later on in script.